# No RAID boot menu on system start up

Tags: boot, bios, raid

I have an HP Pavilion Elite HPE. I used to have an onboard RAID boot up screen but now I do not. Could this have vanished based on a glitch with using a different graphics card or the slow that it is in?

I've tried countless key combinations but I still fail to get it despite what I try in the BIOS menu.

What else could I try besides removing the graphics card and placing in another one and trying different slots to see if that works. That is the only really difference that I can think of that would cause this.

EDIT:
Tried old video card in old slot like how the system came. Nothing. Weird.

Still searching google and people say to hit F1 or F2 and many other ways of trying CTRL+I but nothing works for me. I know it had worked before.

EDIT: Could it be that I need to wipe these drives first so that they are clean and are detected blank and usable? Not sure how these embedded(fake) RAIDs work.

Comment: Existance of the bios at post should not ever have anything to do with the drives, unless somehow a damaged drive was causing an issue , i have never heard of such thing, but we know that a non-responding drive can instead hold things up at init.   A combination of a monitor that takes it's time to show the first view, and a raid bios that is fast , could have you trying keys , but generally you would see it for at least a few seconds if it exists (and turned on in the case of onboard).  Some raid bioses you see them for freaking ever :-)  the intel one can be fairly fast.

Comment: Well I tried the drive idea but nothing. The BIOS kicks in and then boots directly to the boot order menu. Te Intel RAID POST should take place before that. I am not sure what broke it or how to fix it to get it back. The only option to control is the RAID option for the SATA ports. Bummer ;/

Answer (score 1):

Boot into your BIOS and and make sure onboard RAID is enabled.  Perhaps you disabled it by accident?  Its highly unlikely that changing graphics cards would cause the issue.  If it is disabled, enable it - obviously.  If it enabled, it *is* possible the graphics card's BIOS could prevent you from seeing it... still not likely, but replace the card to be sure.

Comment: Hey, I've done reset on the BIOS and the RAID option was enabled hence why I am thinking it might be the BIOS on the video card causing the problem. Will try the original card and try swapping slots and see if that works in anyway.